# How to get all the entries from a LinkedHashMap in Java?

Tags: java

I am using String object as the key to a linkedhashmap.

How can I get all the entries in the LinkedHashMap?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have three options that depend on whether you need just keys, just values or both

```
Set<String> keys = yourMap.keySet();
Collection<YourValueClass> values = yourMap.values();
Set<Map.Entry<String,YourValueClass>> pairs = yourMap.entrySet();
```

then you can easily iterate over them if you need. Actually all of them allow iterating using a simple foreach loop:

```
for (Map.Entry<String,YourClassValue> e : yourMap.entrySet())
  // do something
```

Comment: simple and beautiful answer (+1)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`entrySet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29) method, which returns a set containing the key-value pairs in your map.